# angularjs ui-route: change only 1 nested view and save other views from reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-route-segment

dummy project download [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvA-RVL4BoZi2Womb9r3zw1Mpfkx)`

```
--mainview
--mainview/about
--mainview/about/leftcontainer
--mainview/about/rightcontainer
```

**Problem**

I have a button on about **change right side column** that changes the view of `rightcontainer` `ui-view` but it also refreshes the left-hand side `ui-view`.

**Elaboration**

When you will run the project provided above. The first page you will see is

[image]

Please make some clicks on the buttons provided (as below)

[image]

then click on `change right side column`
[image]

It will refresh the count of left-hand side column.

Please help me to change only a specific view instead of all its siblings

**route code**

```
stateProvider
.state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    views: {
        // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'partial-about.html',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.count = 1;
                $scope.countPlus = function () {
                    $scope.count++;
                }
            }
        },

        // the child views will be defined here (absolutely named)
        'columnOne@about': {
            template: 'Look I am a column! <br> press count    <input type="button" ng-click="countPlus()" value="count++" /> {{count}}',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.count = 1;
                $scope.countPlus = function () {
                    $scope.count++;
                }
            }
        },

        // for column two, we'll define a separate controller 
        'columnTwo@about': {
            templateUrl: 'table-data.html',
            controller: 'scotchController'
        }
    }

})

.state('about.changeRightSideColumn', {
    url: '/changeRightSideColumn',
    views: {
        // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
       // the child views will be defined here (absolutely named)
        'columnOne@about': {
            template: 'Look I am a column! <br> press count    <input type="button" ng-click="countPlus()" value="count++" /> {{count}}',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.count = 1;
                $scope.countPlus = function () {
                    $scope.count++;
                }
            }
        },

        // for column two, we'll define a separate controller 
        'columnTwo@about': {
            templateUrl: 'right-side-column.html'
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you change both the columns in right column handling. If you change the `app.js` code as follows it will work as you expect.

Your Code:

```
.state('about.changeRightSideColumn', {
        url: '/changeRightSideColumn',
        views: {
            // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
           // the child views will be defined here (absolutely named)
            'columnOne@about': {
                template: 'Look I am a column! <br> press count    <input type="button" ng-click="countPlus()" value="count++" /> {{count}}',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.count = 1;
                    $scope.countPlus = function () {
                        $scope.count++;
                    }
                }
            },

            // for column two, we'll define a separate controller 
            'columnTwo@about': {
                templateUrl: 'right-side-column.html'
            }
        }

    }
```

Solution:

```
.state('about.changeRightSideColumn', {
        url: '/changeRightSideColumn',
        views: {
            // for column two, we'll define a separate controller 
            'columnTwo@about': {
                templateUrl: 'right-side-column.html'
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.